# How to push a particular file to github without pushing all other files?

Tags: git, github, push

If I have two different files in local git repository, and i Want to push a single file to cloud repository., How do I do it.?

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here. You don't push files, you push commits. Just commit what you want to push and then push it.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is ignore changes to a particular file.
If so, then the answer is **.gitignore**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git add path_to_single_file

git commit -m "message"

git push